# How is an "isa?" based multimethod more than syntax sugar for instanceof?

Tags: clojure, instanceof, double-dispatch, multimethod

I am taking an example from the [clojure site](https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods#_isa_based_dispatch).

```
(defmulti foo class)
(defmethod foo ::collection [c] :a-collection)
(defmethod foo String [s] :a-string)

(foo [])
:a-collection

(foo (java.util.HashMap.))
:a-collection

(foo "bar")
:a-string
```

This functionality is cool. I'm trying to understand the technical reasons why this is superior to an instanceof based implementation in (for example) java. It seems to me essentially equivalent in function with nicer syntax.

```
public <T> String foo(final T t) {
    if (t instanceof Collection) {
        return "a-collection";
    } else if (t instanceof String) {
        return "a-string";
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Undefined - no available dispatch");
    }
}
```

What are the reasons why multimethods are considered a great alternative to visitor pattern based double dispatch while instanceof is not when they seem like they're essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: here's an example for different dispatch strategies and is-a relationships (using `derive`): https://slides.com/jochenbedersdorfer/clojure-for-java-developers/#/4/3

Comment: What happens when `foo` isn't under your control? Say a user wants to add another option to `foo`. Which version will be easier to extend?

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference Carcigenicate. Foo is just a function you can define anywhere whether multimethod or method using instanceof.

Comment: @Daniel The difference is that I can unilaterally decide to define a new foo method to define and maintain functionality for a new class without touching the existing implementation.

Comment: The multimethod is not really equivalent to the `instanceof` version. It's a bit like saying that a function that returns `x^2` is equivalent to `64` because in your code you only ever call `square(8)`. The `instanceof` version pre-determines all of the possible classes of `t` in advance. An equivalent method would say "get the class of `t` and search all of the loaded code for a method meant to be called when `t` has that class." That class doesn't even need to have existed when you wrote the original code.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part. So you can define foo to handle a bunch of cases and someone else can extend it later without access to the code to handle more cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the benefits discussed in the comments is that the `defmulti` and `defmethod` can be done in different files, by different users.  An excellent example is Clojure's own `print-method` multi-method.

[From the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/print-method), we see how we can define a custom `print-method` for a new record type we create:

```
(deftype XYZ [])

; without custom print-method defined:
user=> (prn (XYZ.))
#<XYZ user.XYZ@2670d85b> 

; Note, this hooks into the pre-existing `(defmulti print-method ...)`
(defmethod print-method XYZ [v ^java.io.Writer w] 
  (.write w "<<-XYZ->>"))

; with print-method
user=> (prn (XYZ.))
<<-XYZ->>
```

So while it has similarity to a giant `cond` statement, it is more flexible & cleaner.